# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code after revoking all certificates in a keychain

Tags: xcode, keychain, code-signing-certificate

I have replaced my keychain password and it deleted all the items in it. I started getting the
`Item not found in a keychain` error, so I regenerated development certificates, and now on every project, I get `Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`

I have tried

- locking and unlocking login in Keychain Acess
- cleaning build folder
- restarting my mac
- pod deintegrate pod install
- re-deleting keychain
- restore previous keychain

This issue shows itself only while building on a real device

At this point I have no idea what can I do to make this error go away.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this situation is an absolute joke, but that what helped me to solve this.

1. Restoring all my previous keychains
2. Deleting all certificates to my name in each of them.